# Wanted to Get The Corresponding Message Details Against Message ID

Tags: solace, solace-mq

As we know we can not read the message in Solace Appliance, However we can see the message ID in Solace Appliance.

So I Wanted to Get The Corresponding Message Details Against Message ID.

How to get the details for same.

Answer (score 1):

> As we know we can not read the message in Solace Appliance, However we
>   can see the message ID in Solace Appliance.

This is not accurate.
In order to protect confidential data, management users cannot view the content of messages. However, application users(with the necessary permissions) can create a browser to view the contents of a message without deleting it.

> So I Wanted to Get The Corresponding Message Details Against Message
>   ID. How to get the details for same.

Use a queue browser to view the full contents of the message.

Alternatively, as a management user, you can view basic information.

```
solace> show queue myqueue message-vpn default messages detail

Name: myqueue

Message Id: 160443684
  Date spooled:                 Jul 11 2016 12:34:02 UTC
  Publisher Id:                 19456
  Sequence Number:              n/a
  Dead Message Queue Eligible:  no
  Content:                      0.0000 MB
  Attachment:                   0.0001 MB
  Replicated:                   no
  Replicated Mate Message Id:   n/a
  Sent:                         no
  Redeliveries:                 0
```